# How to copy my home directory into another user?

Tags: menu-bar

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I think one of the updates damaged something. I now have no menus. I did discover that I can create a second user. This user has all functioning menus. My goal is to copy my home directory into the second user, resulting in a complete functioning machine.
Can you walk me through the process?

Comment: You coulf copy the home directory with `cp -r /home/olduser/* /home/newuser`. But I would recommend troubleshooting your problem first.

Comment: It may be easier to resolve the missing menu bar problem. See “[Menu bar and launcher missing](/q/286088/175814)” or [search for “missing menu bar”](/search?q=missing+menu+bar).

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use the 'sudo' command: `sudo cp /home/olduser/* /home/newuser`. By default Ubuntu does not install a 'root' user. So when you type 'sudo', it will ask you for your password and you enter your normal password. But you (your username) must also be listed in /etc/sudoers.

To edit /etc/sudoers:

1. `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`.  (Nano is an editor installed by default so it should be there.)
2. For more info on this file, do: `man sudoers`.
3. For my Ubuntu 14.04, I just noticed my user is not in /etc/sudoers, yet I can use sudo just fine.